# Codeigniter passing objects within views

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am loading a view from a Controller file and that View loads another view which a final one as below,

```
First view Call : 

    Controller: device.php

        public function device_name(){
           $data = new stdClass;
           $data->device_name = "Apple";
           $this->load->view('apple_device',$data);
        }

Second view call :

    View: In apple_device.php

       $device_name->count = 123;
       $this->load->view('device_counts',$device_name);
```

I am using object here instead of an array as a passing variable between views. But if i use array, it works fine.

And the above code throwing error as like below,

```
Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should only pass the data as an array

Comment: No. We can also pass an object into a view. Ref: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may still pass through objects, but not at the 'first level', you'll need to wrap the object you want to pass through inside an array.

```
public function device_name(){
    $mobiles = new stdClass;
    $mobiles->device_name = "Apple";
    $data = array( "mobiles" => $mobiles );
    $this->load->view('apple_device',$data);
}
```

This is because when CodeIgniter will initialize the view, it will check the  contents of the second [`view()`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L457) parameter. If it's an object - it'll cast it to an array via [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) (See [`github` link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L1345))

```
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object)
{
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
}
```

Which will in turn, turn your initial `$data` into:

```
$data = new stdClass;
$data->device_name = "Apple";
$example = get_object_vars( $data );
print_r( $example );

Array ( [device_name] => Apple )
```

Thus to avoid this, nest  your object inside an `array()` which will avoid being converted.